# MAXIF condition in excel with two if conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel query : I have columns named as car name, date of sell and time of sell... I need to find the latest sold time and date when i input a particular car name.... (I tried using maxif function but i can only get latest date but cant proceed further to get max time within same date) Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You need to add time and date, e.g with this array formula, assuming a specific car name in D2

=MAX(IF(carname=D2,date+time))

Confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

No text allowed in date or time ranges

that gives you the Max time and date within one cell - format result cell to show time and date in required format, e.g.

m/d/yy hh:mm